# How to save result of a TCL proc in a list?

Tags: tcl, proc

My TCL script is like this:

```
proc foo {var1} {
    ;# some code which finds a value (say bar) and recursively call the same proc (foo) on bar until it reaches end of data.
}
```

Now I want to save all the values (bar) to a list.

When I set a list inside the proc, it resets every time the proc is recursively called. When I set outside the proc, it doesn't find it and says variable doesn't exists.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Edit:

Below is the sample code:

```
set mylist {}

proc myproc {var} {

set exception {tesla}
set var1 [#some script to fetch a data string using proc variable]

foreach item $var1 {
    set var2 [#script to get another data depending on item]

    if {$var1==2 || $var2=="tesla"} {

        set var3 [#script to get some data using var2]

        puts "debug value $var3"
        lappend mylist $var3
        myproc $var3
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1

```
proc foo {var1 resultVar} {
    upvar $resultVar result
    if {$var1 == 1} {
        lappend result 1 
        return $result
    } else {
        lappend result $var1
        foo [expr $var1 - 1] result
    }
}

set myResults []
foo 10 myResults
puts "From foo: $myResults"
```

Solution 2

```
proc bar {var1} {
    global barResults
    if {$var1 == 1} {
        lappend barResults 1 
    } else {
        lappend barResults $var1
        bar [expr $var1 - 1]
    }
}

set barResults []
bar 10
puts "From bar: $barResults"
```

Output

```
sharad@ss:~$ tclsh my.tcl 
From foo: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
From bar: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
sharad@ss:~$
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, when you're working through a list like that with a searching step, it's usual to update the list so that it contains just the elements remaining to search through. The list itself is stored in a variable in the caller that is provided to the called routine; if it's in a local variable, it won't affect the outside world. The name-provision is used with `upvar` so that the inner search procedure doesn't need to have built-in knowledge about the naming of variables in its caller (because that'd be *terrible* style). The caller can copy the list into a local variable if that is necessary

```
proc innerSearch {listVariable} {
    upvar 1 $listVariable theList
    set idx [...];            # Get index of thing we found
    set resultValue [...];    # Thing that we will return
    set theList [lrange $theList [expr {$idx + 1}] end]
    return $resultValue
}

proc outerSearch {} {
    global foobar
    set myList $foobar;       # Copy here! Actually does efficient magic behind the scenes
    set results {}
    while 1 {
        set foundThing [innerSearch myList];   # Note: we pass the variable *NAME*
        if {$foundThing eq ""} break;          # Terminate the loop if not found
        lappend results $foundThing
    }
    return $results
}
```

If on the other hand you need to also know the index that you found the element at in order to process it, you can arrange for the previous index to be in the variable that is stored, and just pass the list in by value.

```
proc innerSearch {list indexVariable} {
    upvar 1 $indexVariable idx
    # Use old index to start search        
    set idx [...];            # Get index of thing we found
    set resultValue [...];    # Thing that we will return
    return $resultValue
}

proc outerSearch {} {
    global foobar
    set index -1;             # Before any element
    set results {}
    while 1 {
        set foundThing [innerSearch $foobar index];   # Note: we pass the variable *NAME*
        if {$index == -1} break;          # Terminate the loop if not found
        lappend results $foundThing
    }
    return $results
}
```

If you're using the current recommended version of Tcl (8.6) you might be able to convert simple searches into `lmap` calls. I can't tell if that's the case here.

Answer (score 1):

You will need `lappend` to store the output on each recursive call.

```
proc glob-r-dir {{dir .}} {
    set res {}
    foreach i [glob -nocomplain -dir $dir *] {
        if {[file type $i] eq {directory}} {
            lappend res $i
            eval lappend res [glob-r-dir $i] ;# recursive call to function
        }
    }
    set res
}
```

While calling you can call like this,

```
set dirs [glob-r-dir "/home/abc"]
```

Here, you will get your return value in `dir` variable.

I found this here inside "Recursive Glob Section" [Click on This](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1474)

Comment: Thanks AxT, but I couldn't get it to work It returns empty list.
I tried something similar but set res {} is called every time proc is called.
Am I doing something wrong?